# How to apply hibernate validation to Character type?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[M|F]{1}$", message ="Must be M or F")
private Character gender;
```

Result:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Character.
```

How can achieve the following:

- apply hibernate validation to the character using a regex pattern
- restricting the return type to be a single letter (that's why I chose `char`)
- to everything of this in a single method?

Comment: i know it is not your question, but you can change the `gender` to be an `Enum`. Here is one way to do, exactly like your case: [http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example)

Comment: Unfortunately I only used the gender as an example. My regex is much more complex and cannot be refactored to an enum.

Comment: There is not need to use a 'Character' for fulfilling your requirements. If you use a String, your \@Pattern will make sure that the length of the string will be just one character. If you want to make this even more explicit you could even add an additional \@Size constraint.

Comment: I want to also make it clear in code that the size of the field is limited to 1, which can directly be seen by type `char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similiar problem and i didnt find any default hibernate validator annotation for that. But there is easy way to create custom annotation. (look here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html) Below example with sex:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = SexValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Sex
{

    String message() default "{customValidator.sex";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List
    {
        Sex[] value();
    }
}
```

```
public class SexValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Sex, Character> {

    public void initialize(Sex sex)
    {
        // used only if your annotation has attributes
    }

    public boolean isValid(Character sex, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext)
    {
        // Bean Validation specification recommends to consider null values as
        // being valid. If null is not a valid value for an element, it should
        // be annotated with @NotNull explicitly.
        if (sex == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (sex.equals('F') || sex.equals('M'))
            return true;

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

```
@Column(name = "sex", columnDefinition = "char(1)")
@NotNull
@Sex
private Character sex;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an option. Though it feels a bit overengineered if the annotation would be used only on a single field (which is the case in my app). Then it's probably better to create a private validation method with `@AssertTrue isSexValid()` and apply the rule checks there inside.